# How to add "Privacy" details in Google Calendar using Google API Version 2

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, gdata-api, gdata

I am using Google API Version 2  fo .NET to create Google Calendar Entries.
How can we set "Privacy" (Default,Public,Private) in Google Calendar ?

Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EventEntry.EventVisibility` property is what you are looking for.

[image]